# Discover server responsible for serving a PTR for a specific IP?

Tags: nameserver, dig, ptr-record

Just as the title reads: How do I discover what nameserver is the authoritative nameserver for PTR records for a specific IP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or another way using nslookup on an address in the 216.239.32.0 subnet:

```
set type=ns
32.239.216.in-addr.arpa
```

Which will give you a list of name-servers for that reverse-lookup domain.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 That is extremely helpful. Do you know how to perform the same on the top half of, say, a /25 that is reassigned to another party? To elaborate, the command you have here will give you the name servers for the bottom /25, but getting the name servers for the top /25 is eluding me. We tried doing it like `NSLOOKUP -type=NS 128.32.239.216.in-addr.arpa` but didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's kind of obvious, it's late give me a break.

dig XX.XX.XX.in-addr.arpa. will reply with the SOA if one has been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the IP `198.1.1.1` here are the different `dig` commands to use to get the authoritative server (SOA) for different blocks of including this IP:

```
$ dig +short soa -x 198.1.1.1
$
```

means there is no SOA a this level (/32),

```
$ dig +short soa -x 198.1.1
smtdns1. hostmaster. 8 900 600 86400 3600
$
```

means `smtdns1` is the SOA a this level (/24),

```
$ dig +short soa -x 198
z.arin.net. dns-ops.arin.net. 2017029249 1800 900 691200 10800
$
```

means `z.arin.net` i sthe SOA a this level (/8).

Answer (score -1):

IF you are using Linux, try 'dig -x '.

Comment: Please read the question again if you could. I don't want to perform a reverse lookup. I want to know who the authoritative nameserver is given a specific delegation of IP space.

Comment: dig -x would show you that, might not be the best solution but as far as I know it gives you the NS handling the address.<br>dig -x 8.8.8.8 tells ns1 and ns3.level3.net. dig SOA -x 8.8.8.8 will show same information as a dig in-addr.arpa.

Answer (score -1):

DNSStuff.com is a great place - their free tool will show this - as well as some other information for who is responsible for the IP Space - in case you need abuse contact details.

Don't worry - we all know how those late nights go...